# Skype login problem

Tags: skype

I have following strange problem under my Ubuntu 12.04. There is no possibility to start several skype instances. So I ran second skype with `sudo /usr/bin/skype`, logged to
skype and used it without problems. But the next day when I tried to log into the second skype instance with the skype account that I have used yesterday, it showed an error message that I've already used this account from this computer. I tried to start skype with `sudo /usr/bin/skype` and after this I logged with this account without a problem. But now it's impossible to use this account directly without
`sudo` command. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** run Skype with `sudo`! This is extremely unwise, as Skype will have full control over everything. What happened is that running skype as root created the user account with root ownership, disallowing your normal user from accessing the files.

To fix your issue. From a terminal do:

```
sudo chown -R [user]:[user] ~/.Skype/
```

Where [user] is your username.

To start a second Skype you can use:

```
skype --secondary
```